# Trying to follow URL and then download image

Tags: java, image, url, download, instagram

I'm writing a java program that goes out and searches twitter, finds certain instagram links, and then downloads the instagram image to a directory. I've written all of the code to do the twitter searching and image saving but the problem that I'm having is that I get a URL in the following format

`http://t.co/xxxxxxxx`

From the twitter search which then if followed resolves to an instagram URL such as

`http://instagr.am/p/xxxxxxxxxx/`

How can I go about resolving the original URL to the instagram URL and then downloading the appropriate image on that page?

Comment: If you use `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, redirects should be followed by default. Did you try that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instagram provides an API call for this.  It returns everything you would need in JSON format just provide the short URL like:

http://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=http://instagr.am/p/XXXXXX/

And you'll get the data like this:

```
{
    provider_url: "http://instagr.am/",
    title: "Rays",
    url: "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/media/2010/10/02/7e4051fdcf1d45ab9bc1fba2582c0c6b_7.jpg",
    author_name: "danrubin",
    media_id: "5382_72",
    author_id: 72,
    height: 612,
    width: 612,
    version: "1.0",
    author_url: "http://instagr.am/",
    provider_name: "Instagram",
    type: "photo"
}
```

Or if all you want is the image you can just add a /media to the URL:

http://instagr.am/p/XXXXXX/media

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how much your code does, but you should be able to make an HTTP request against that t.co link, and get the `Location` field in the returned headers, which contains the instagr.am link.

Example header response from a t.co link:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 21 Mar 2012 04:48:00 GMT
Server: hi
Location: http://instagr.am/p/XXXXXX/
Cache-Control: private,max-age=300
Expires: Wed, 21 Mar 2012 04:53:00 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

As you can see, the `Location` field is the one you want to parse out.